# Is there a tool to test the tab order of desktop applications?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, gui

We want to ensure decent keyboard navigation for our products. Currently, this is a manual test we perform. Are there any tools that can assist in this task?

I can imagine a visual representation of the tab order which helps to inspect the order of an entire dialog at a glance. Something like a graph connecting the various input fields in tab order.

Similarly, is there something to test access-keys as well?

Comment: What GUI technology are you using?

Comment: We are using Delphi VCL and .NET Winforms as well as WPF. I was hoping for something technology agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

> We want to ensure decent **keyboard navigation** for our products.

Sikuli is a good option. But if the application is on Windows, then I would rather use SeeShell for that.

Its `type` command supports [all Windows shortcuts](https://a9t9.com/seeshell/docs#keys) and combinations, more than Sikuli can do since it is a cross-platform app.

Answer (score 0):

Before couple of months i did some Desktop automation using Sikuli..Sikuli may be helpful to you

Here i mentioned few Practical Uses of sikuli

- **Using Sikuli we can automate desktop applications.**
- It provides, simple API. i.e. all methods can be accessed using
  screen class object.
- **It can be easily integrated with Selenium and all other tools.**
- Most of the automation testing tools will not support flash object
  automation (E.g. Selenium). Sikuli provides extensive support to
  automate flash objects. It uses powerful “Visual Match” mechanism to
  **automate desktop & flash objects**.

Answer (score 0):

In our automation testing company we have used Sikuli, Winium to automate desktop application. Navigation between tab would not be a problem.

Sikuli works on image comparison. We need to capture tab image and when test runs, it matches the image with actual tab image. If it matches scripts passes
Winium works on objet Ids as locators.

There are paid tools also such as Ranorex, Test Complete which would also solves your purpose.